# Access violation registering Canvas classes

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have been getting a few bug reports for an access violation that occurs while registering Canvas classes at startup, more specifically performing an `@IntfClear` during `TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice`.

Full bugreport:

```
date/time         : 2014-06-04, 18:05:43, 594ms
computer name     : <...>
user name         : <...>
registered owner  : <...>
operating system  : Windows 7 x64 Service Pack 1 build 7601
system language   : English
system up time    : 54 minutes 48 seconds
program up time   : 99 milliseconds
processors        : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 661 @ 3.33GHz
physical memory   : 5055/8055 MB (free/total)
free disk space   : (C:) 91.84 GB
display mode      : 1920x1080, 32 bit
process id        : $18c0
allocated memory  : 71.76 MB
executable        : <...>.exe
exec. date/time   : 2014-05-29 22:36
version           : 3.2.1.2
compiled with     : Delphi XE3
madExcept version : 4.0.6
callstack crc     : $077d2d6c, $53160fd9, $53160fd9
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EAccessViolation
exception message : Zugriffsverletzung bei Adresse 077D2D6C. Lesen von Adresse 000000AE.

main thread ($d0):
077d2d6c +000 ???
0040e028 +010 <...>.exe System            191  +0 @IntfClear
0096af25 +0cd <...>.exe FMX.Context.DX10          TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice
00976559 +005 <...>.exe FMX.Canvas.D2D            RegisterCanvasClasses
00990c6c +000 <...>.exe FMX.Platform.Win 3404  +0 TPlatformWin.RegisterCanvasClasses
009d6312 +056 <...>.exe FMX.Types                 TCanvasManager.GetDefaultCanvas
009d62aa +00e <...>.exe FMX.Types                 TCanvasManager.CreateFromWindow
00a0574e +026 <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TCustomForm.CreateHandle
009fff91 +0b9 <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TCommonCustomForm.InitializeNewForm
00a054fa +006 <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TCustomForm.InitializeNewForm
009ffce4 +094 <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TCommonCustomForm.Create
00a056c6 +016 <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TCustomForm.Create
009fb947 +057 <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TApplication.CreateForm
009fbb0b +05f <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TApplication.RealCreateForms
00988861 +011 <...>.exe FMX.Platform.Win  461  +1 TPlatformWin.Run
009fe821 +0d1 <...>.exe FMX.Forms                 TApplication.Run
00beccf4 +2c0 <...>.exe <...>             106 +39 initialization
75863388 +010 kernel32.dll                                  BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $186c:
778a0156 +0e ntdll.dll                     NtWaitForMultipleObjects
76e715f1 +fa KERNELBASE.dll                WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
758619f3 +89 kernel32.dll                  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
75330864 +00 USER32.dll                    MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
75330b64 +1a USER32.dll                    MsgWaitForMultipleObjects
004a42e9 +0d <...>.exe madExcept CallThreadProcSafe
004a434e +32 <...>.exe madExcept ThreadExceptFrame
75863388 +10 kernel32.dll                  BaseThreadInitThunk
>> created by main thread ($d0) at:
734878e1 +00 gdiplus.dll

thread $1288: <priority:1>
7789f8ca +0e ntdll.dll                     NtWaitForSingleObject
76e714a5 +92 KERNELBASE.dll                WaitForSingleObjectEx
7586118f +3e kernel32.dll                  WaitForSingleObjectEx
75861143 +0d kernel32.dll                  WaitForSingleObject
004a42e9 +0d <...>.exe madExcept CallThreadProcSafe
004a434e +32 <...>.exe madExcept ThreadExceptFrame
75863388 +10 kernel32.dll                  BaseThreadInitThunk
>> created by main thread ($d0) at:
54377390 +00 nvwgf2um.dll

thread $28c:
778a1f3f +0b ntdll.dll     NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
75863388 +10 kernel32.dll  BaseThreadInitThunk

thread $1bcc:
778a1f3f +0b ntdll.dll     NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
75863388 +10 kernel32.dll  BaseThreadInitThunk

modules:
00400000 <...>.exe                                3.2.1.2            C:\<...>
10000000 nvspcap.dll                              10.11.15.0         C:\Windows\system32
53c10000 nvwgf2um.dll                             9.18.13.2723       C:\Windows\system32
603d0000 AcGenral.DLL                             6.1.7601.18128     C:\Windows\AppPatch
606d0000 atkdx11disp.dll                          7.14.10.305        C:\Windows\system32
60700000 d3d10_1core.dll                          6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\system32
60750000 d3d10_1.dll                              6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\system32
60780000 security.dll                             6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
60790000 FaultRep.dll                             6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
607f0000 sfc_os.DLL                               6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
60800000 sfc.dll                                  6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
6ed00000 d3d11.dll                                6.2.9200.16570     C:\Windows\system32
706d0000 dxgi.dll                                 6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\system32
70ca0000 propsys.dll                              7.0.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
70e00000 d3d9.dll                                 6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
70fd0000 nvapi.dll                                9.18.13.2723       C:\Windows\system32
71a50000 comctl32.dll                             6.10.7601.17514    C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2
71bf0000 winmm.dll                                6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
72150000 samcli.dll                               6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
73210000 MSACM32.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
73230000 d3d8thk.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
73440000 gdiplus.dll                              6.1.7601.18120     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.18120_none_72d2e82386681b36
73890000 apphelp.dll                              6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
738e0000 MPR.dll                                  6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
73ca0000 wsock32.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
73f20000 SECUR32.DLL                              6.1.7601.18443     C:\Windows\system32
74090000 dwmapi.dll                               6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
74100000 UxTheme.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
742e0000 comctl32.dll                             5.82.7601.18201    C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5
74f90000 profapi.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
74fa0000 USERENV.dll                              6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
750b0000 ntmarta.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
750e0000 sophos_detoured.dll                      10.3.3.128         C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos Anti-Virus
75130000 winspool.drv                             6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
75190000 version.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\system32
752a0000 CRYPTBASE.dll                            6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\syswow64
752b0000 SspiCli.dll                              6.1.7601.18443     C:\Windows\syswow64
75310000 USER32.dll                               6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
75410000 iertutil.dll                             11.0.9600.17041    C:\Windows\syswow64
75630000 SETUPAPI.dll                             6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
757d0000 PSAPI.DLL                                6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\syswow64
757e0000 api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll 6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\syswow64
757f0000 NSI.dll                                  6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\syswow64
75800000 WLDAP32.dll                              6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
75850000 kernel32.dll                             6.1.7601.18409     C:\Windows\syswow64
759f0000 DEVOBJ.dll                               6.1.7601.17621     C:\Windows\syswow64
75a10000 RPCRT4.dll                               6.1.7601.18205     C:\Windows\syswow64
75b00000 WININET.dll                              11.0.9600.17041    C:\Windows\syswow64
75cc0000 shell32.dll                              6.1.7601.18429     C:\Windows\syswow64
76910000 WS2_32.dll                               6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
769b0000 api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll 6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\syswow64
769c0000 MSCTF.dll                                6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\syswow64
76a90000 comdlg32.dll                             6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
76b10000 api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll  6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\syswow64
76b50000 msvcrt.dll                               7.0.7601.17744     C:\Windows\syswow64
76c00000 api-ms-win-downlevel-ole32-l1-1-0.dll    6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\syswow64
76c10000 ole32.dll                                6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
76d70000 normaliz.DLL                             6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\syswow64
76d80000 CLBCatQ.DLL                              2001.12.8530.16385 C:\Windows\syswow64
76e10000 CFGMGR32.dll                             6.1.7601.17621     C:\Windows\syswow64
76e40000 sechost.dll                              6.1.7600.16385     C:\Windows\SysWOW64
76e60000 KERNELBASE.dll                           6.1.7601.18409     C:\Windows\syswow64
76eb0000 IMM32.DLL                                6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\system32
76f10000 USP10.dll                                1.626.7601.18009   C:\Windows\syswow64
76fb0000 WINTRUST.dll                             6.1.7601.18205     C:\Windows\syswow64
76fe0000 api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll  6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\syswow64
76ff0000 CRYPT32.dll                              6.1.7601.18277     C:\Windows\syswow64
77110000 MSASN1.dll                               6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
77120000 ADVAPI32.dll                             6.1.7601.18247     C:\Windows\syswow64
771c0000 oleaut32.dll                             6.1.7601.17676     C:\Windows\syswow64
77250000 SHLWAPI.dll                              6.1.7601.17514     C:\Windows\syswow64
772b0000 api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll   6.2.9200.16492     C:\Windows\syswow64
772c0000 GDI32.dll                                6.1.7601.18275     C:\Windows\syswow64
77350000 urlmon.dll                               11.0.9600.17041    C:\Windows\syswow64
77850000 LPK.dll                                  6.1.7601.18177     C:\Windows\syswow64
77880000 ntdll.dll                                6.1.7601.18247     C:\Windows\SysWOW64

processes:
0000 Idle                     0 0   0
0004 System                   0 0   0
0120 smss.exe                 0 0   0
01c8 csrss.exe                0 0   0
0210 wininit.exe              0 0   0
0224 csrss.exe                1 0   0
0250 services.exe             0 0   0
0260 lsass.exe                0 0   0
0268 lsm.exe                  0 0   0
02d4 winlogon.exe             1 0   0
02f4 svchost.exe              0 0   0
0330 ATKFUSService.exe        0 0   0
0344 nvvsvc.exe               0 0   0
0360 nvSCPAPISvr.exe          0 0   0
038c svchost.exe              0 0   0
03c8 atiesrxx.exe             0 0   0
03f8 svchost.exe              0 0   0
014c svchost.exe              0 0   0
0298 svchost.exe              0 0   0
0228 svchost.exe              0 0   0
0454 audiodg.exe              0 0   0
04ac SavService.exe           0 0   0
04b8 atieclxx.exe             1 0   0
04c8 nvxdsync.exe             1 0   0
04d0 nvvsvc.exe               1 0   0
0614 ATKFastUserSwitching.exe 1 18  11  normal
0660 dwm.exe                  1 18  2   high
0678 explorer.exe             1 356 266 normal
0790 svchost.exe              0 0   0
07e4 svchost.exe              0 0   0
0490 spoolsv.exe              0 0   0
082c taskhost.exe             1 25  23  normal
08d0 NvTmru.exe               1 9   4   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA Update Core
0924 NvBackend.exe            1 9   4   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\Update Core
0944 ANIWConnService.exe      0 0   0
0980 ANIWZCSdS.exe            0 0   0
099c RtlService.exe           0 0   0
09dc flux.exe                 1 22  13  normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\FluxSoftware\Flux
09f4 SpotifyWebHelper.exe     1 9   3   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Data
0a3c nvtray.exe               1 81  5   normal
0a74 BCUService.exe           0 0   0
0aac FABS.exe                 0 0   0
0ae0 RtWLan.exe               1 0   0
0b48 NvNetworkService.exe     0 0   0
0ba8 nvstreamsvc.exe          0 0   0
0610 spotify.exe              1 222 81  normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Roaming\Spotify
046c razerhid.exe             1 9   5   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Arctosa
09c8 BCU.exe                  1 9   4   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\DeviceVM\Browser Configuration Utility
0b9c jusched.exe              1 9   2   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update
0b84 PnkBstrA.exe             0 0   0
0910 PnkBstrB.exe             0 0   0
0920 SAVAdminService.exe      0 0   0
09d4 ALsvc.exe                0 0   0
0c70 swc_service.exe          0 0   0
0c98 svchost.exe              0 0   0
0cac swi_service.exe          0 0   0
0cec TurboBoost.exe           0 0   0
0d30 ALMon.exe                1 47  40  normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\AutoUpdate
0d60 WLIDSVC.EXE              0 0   0
0e04 WLIDSVCM.EXE             0 0   0
0efc WmiPrvSE.exe             0 0   0
0ff0 SearchIndexer.exe        0 0   0
0af0 svchost.exe              0 0   0
11b8 nvstreamsvc.exe          1 0   0
11cc conhost.exe              1 0   0
127c wmpnetwk.exe             0 0   0
130c svchost.exe              0 0   0
11d0 svchost.exe              0 0   0
1304 SpotifyHelper.exe        1 52  1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Data
1134 SpotifyHelper.exe        1 33  1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Data
15c8 SpotifyHelper.exe        1 13  3   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Data
17a8 dllhost.exe              0 0   0
151c LMS.exe                  0 0   0
14b0 svchost.exe              0 0   0
1018 UNS.exe                  0 0   0
059c SpotifyHelper.exe        1 142 1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Data
08d8 SpotifyHelper.exe        1 11  1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Data
0abc chrome.exe               1 375 53  normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
0eb4 chrome.exe               1 12  5   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
12d8 chrome.exe               1 11  1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
0da8 chrome.exe               1 719 1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
10bc chrome.exe               1 11  1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
1114 chrome.exe               1 9   1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
0968 chrome.exe               1 11  1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
1220 chrome.exe               1 10  1   normal       C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
1974 jucheck.exe              1 12  6   normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update
0778 chrome.exe               1 251 1   below normal C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
1144 WINWORD.EXE              1 474 118 normal       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14
0cc4 OSPPSVC.EXE              0 0   0
17b8 splwow64.exe             1 4   2   normal
1410 SearchProtocolHost.exe   0 0   0
1258 SearchFilterHost.exe     0 0   0   idle
18e0 chrome.exe               1 209 1   below normal C:\Users\<...>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
18c0 <...>.exe      1 36  34  normal       C:\<...>

cpu registers:
eax = 00000000
ebx = 00000000
ecx = 00000000
edx = 00000008
esi = 0018fca4
edi = 077d2d6c
eip = 077d2d6c
esp = 0018fc60
ebp = 077d2444

stack dump:
0018fc60  a4 fc 18 00 44 24 7d 07 - 6c 2d 7d 07 44 24 00 06  ....D$}.l-}.D$..
0018fc70  2c 63 de 6e 48 81 7d 07 - 6c 2d 7d 07 00 00 00 00  ,c.nH.}.l-}.....
0018fc80  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ac fc 18 00 42 00 d2 6e  ............B..n
0018fc90  6c 2d 7d 07 01 00 00 00 - 58 25 7d 07 44 24 7d 07  l-}.....X%}.D$}.
0018fca0  3c 27 7d 07 3c 27 7d 07 - 3c a6 d0 6e c0 fc 18 00  <'}.<'}.<..n....
0018fcb0  1b ff d1 6e 6c 2d 7d 07 - 44 24 7d 07 a0 00 00 00  ...nl-}.D$}.....
0018fcc0  cc fc 18 00 43 25 d1 6e - 3c 27 7d 07 e0 fc 18 00  ....C%.n<'}.....
0018fcd0  6d 6d d1 6e fc 26 7d 07 - 00 00 00 00 3c 24 7d 07  mm.n.&}.....<$}.
0018fce0  ec fc 18 00 f1 26 d1 6e - 10 24 7d 07 f8 fc 18 00  .....&.n.$}.....
0018fcf0  52 c1 d4 6e 3c 24 7d 07 - 14 fd 18 00 5f 39 d1 6e  R..n<$}....._9.n
0018fd00  10 24 7d 07 04 34 d1 6e - 10 24 7d 07 66 38 d1 6e  .$}..4.n.$}.f8.n
0018fd10  10 24 7d 07 28 fd 18 00 - 5f 34 d1 6e 00 00 00 00  .$}.(..._4.n....
0018fd20  16 00 00 00 90 05 00 00 - 34 fd 18 00 c5 25 d1 6e  ........4....%.n
0018fd30  10 24 7d 07 40 fd 18 00 - d1 f5 d4 6e 3c 27 7d 07  .$}.@......n<'}.
0018fd40  84 fd 18 00 2b e0 40 00 - 74 27 7d 07 80 fd 18 00  ....+.@.t'}.....
0018fd50  2a af 96 00 60 fd 18 00 - 9c 98 40 00 84 fd 18 00  *...`.....@.....
0018fd60  6c fd 18 00 9c 98 40 00 - 84 fd 18 00 94 fd 18 00  l.....@.........
0018fd70  9c 98 40 00 84 fd 18 00 - a0 00 00 00 00 00 75 60  ..@...........u`
0018fd80  00 00 00 00 bc fd 18 00 - 5e 65 97 00 71 0c 99 00  ........^e..q...
0018fd90  15 63 9d 00 10 fe 18 00 - 9c 98 40 00 bc fd 18 00  .c........@.....

disassembling:
[...]
0040e01c       jz      loc_40e02c
0040e01e       mov     dword ptr [eax], 0
0040e024       push    eax
0040e025       push    edx
0040e026       mov     eax, [edx]
0040e028     > call    dword ptr [eax+8]
0040e02b       pop     eax
0040e02c       ret
```

This is by no means happening on all machines but seems to be a very rare issue.

---

EDIT:

Following the suggestion of @Graymatter I've been able to establish an SSCCE.

```
program SSCCE;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses System.SysUtils, FMX.Context.DX10;

begin
  try
    TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice;
    WriteLn('Everything went fine, guess we have to dig deeper.');
  except
    on E: Exception do Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Write('Press enter to exit.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The output produced is `Zugriffsverletzung bei Adresse 05C1006C. Lesen von Adresse 06F29ED3` Any suggestions as to what to do about that ?

Comment: Bug reports are great, but they mean nothing if we can't see the code which caused it.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, but none of the code I've written is in the stack trace and the project has many thousand loc, so I really don't know what might be relevant. I was thinking it must be a more basic issue since it doesn't even get past initialization and none of my units has an initialization section.

Comment: Is DirectX 10 installed on the computers in question?

Comment: According to [this link](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2005/03/31/3593/) this might have to do with using an interface on a class which does not implement reference counting. Is it the TCustomDXContext itself that @IntfClear is being called on?

Comment: Yes, from the module list the dx10 dll seems to be loaded. I'm not exactly sure what the @IntfClear is being called on, but since it's an FMX unit I doubt it's a major bug like that.

Comment: Hah! Doubt FMX. It's a giant bug factory. What you need to do now is make that SSCCE.

Comment: Based on the link overactor gave. You can try setting GlobalUseDX10Software to true. That will force software mode. That will skip out the portion that creates the D10 device. If that succeeds then you know the problem is probably setting the g_pd3dDevice to nil.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Working on it, but it might take some time since the issue is not occurring on my machine.

Comment: In this case I think you are going to battle to get a valid SSCCE. This seems to be related to the environment. A SSCCE would probably be a simple command line application that includes FMX.Context.DX10 and then call TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice.

Comment: Do the machines in question have DX10 or DX10.1 installed? Looking on the internet it seems like FMX only supports DX10.1.

Comment: The loaded module is d3d10_1.dll so I'd assume it's DX10.1.

Comment: I have updated the main post with an SSCCE.