# Exception clearing interface in TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046083/access-violation-registering-canvas-classes). I realize I did a poor job of narrowing down the issue myself in that one, apologies. I now have a very specific idea of what is going on, so hopefully somebody is going to be able to push me in the right direction.

SSCCE:

```
program SSCCE;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses System.SysUtils, FMX.Context.DX10;

begin
  try
    TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice;
    WriteLn('Everything went fine, guess we have to dig deeper.');
  except
    on E: Exception do Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Write('Press enter to exit.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

CheckDevice produces an access violation in `@IntfClear`. This is the code for CheckDevice in FMX.Context.DX10:

```
class function TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice: TD3D10DriverType;
var
  dx10lib: THandle;
  g_pd3dDevice: ID3D10Device1;
begin
  if not FChecked then
  begin
    FChecked := True;
    FDriverType := D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
    dx10lib := LoadLibrary(D3D10_1_dll);
    if dx10lib <> 0 then
    try
      if GlobalUseDX10Software then
        FDriverType := D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP
      else begin
        if GlobalUseDX10 then
        begin
          { check for support for DX10 hardware }
          SaveClearFPUState;
          try
            if GetProcAddress(dx10lib, 'D3D10CreateDevice1') <> nil then
            begin
              if Succeeded(D3D10CreateDevice1(nil, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 0, D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, D3D10_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D10_1_SDK_VERSION, g_pd3dDevice)) then
              begin
                g_pd3dDevice := nil;
                FDriverType := D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;
              end;
            end;
          finally
            RestoreFPUState;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(dx10Lib);
    end;
  end;
  Result := FDriverType;
end;
```

I have made the user who is having the issues try a few variations, and I could confirm that as soon as the reference to `g_pd3dDevice` runs out of scope, `@IntfClear` is being called and subsequently produces an access violation.

```
0040e028 +010 <...>.exe System            191  +0 @IntfClear
0096a360 +0d0 <...>.exe FMX.Context.DX10  314 +20 TCustomDX10Context.CheckDevice
009759a1 +005 <...>.exe FMX.Canvas.D2D            RegisterCanvasClasses
009900b4 +000 <...>.exe FMX.Platform.Win 3404  +0 TPlatformWin.RegisterCanvasClasses
009d575a +056 <...>.exe FMX.Types                 TCanvasManager.GetDefaultCanvas
009d56f2 +00e <...>.exe FMX.Types                 TCanvasManager.CreateFromWindow
```

314 is the line where `g_pd3dDevice` is being niled after a successful API call, commenting that line out leads to the AV occuring when clearing the interface after it has run out of scope at the end of the function. Could this be caused by `D3D10CreateDevice1` returning an invalid device, or is there something else going on? Also, since the AV comes up in `@IntfClear` I don't think I can just try except it and eat it up, even though this would probably not do too much good either way ...